# Can you add claims to access tokens in AWS Cognito Pre token generation trigger when we use client credential flow

Tags: amazon-cognito

is it possible to add claims to access tokens when we use client credential flow?
I tried but it had no effect

**it works for code grant flow.** Groups appeared in both ID and Access tokens.

my code

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Retrieve user group data from Cognito event
    user_groups = event["request"]["groupConfiguration"]["groupsToOverride"]
    
    # Customize the user's group membership
    user_groups.append("New Group")
    
    # Add the modified user group data to the event response
    event["response"]["claimsOverrideDetails"] = {
        "groupOverrideDetails": {
            "groupsToOverride": user_groups
        }
    }
    
    return event
```

Any claim to access token if that possible

Comment: did you  find solution for this I am having same problem. I want to add scopes to access token in pre token generation trigger